# Converting pyqt ui files into py files

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtgui

So I've recently switched to pyqt from tkinter for my python gui apps, and I love it .

However there is one thing that bugs me and I hope you guys can help me.

I like using the qtdesigner tool so I can rapidly develop interfaces, but when I convert the qui to py, it constructs a class in a slightly unsual way with the setupUi method that setups the main window. I was hoping I could change the way it made the class into a more conventional way with an **init** method so that I could inherit from it and define my events etc from in another file. At the moment I manually do it. This would make it easy to modify the ui in designer and still import from the converted py file without having to make any mods.

I hope my question makes sense, and I am looking forward to hear how other developers out there handle this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally load ui file itself without converting to py. That actually save some time and code also looks nice. Here is a snippet

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic
import sys

# Here you can add your ui path from desigener, no need to convert
RESOURCE_PATH             = package.__BASERESLOC__
baseUI                    = os.path.join(RESOURCE_PATH, "base_main.ui")
baseUIClass, baseUIWidget = uic.loadUiType(baseUI)

class BASEGUICLS(baseUIWidget, baseUIClass):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(BASEGUICLS, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        #after this you will have everything
        self.pushButton.setText("Foo")

def main():
    """
    Main function which init main GUI.
    """
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = BASEGUICLS(None)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this is exactly what I was looking for. Makes it easy to adjust the gui without compromising your code.

Comment: yeah it is actually nice and njoy :)